# Global Application Monitoring macos/cocoa/objective-c

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, cgeventtap

Is there a way to monitor Action had been performed in Applications? For Example the User opens a new TAB in Safari. Im try to monitor these actions. I'm searching for a Class which recognize these kind of actions!!

Anybody a tip or a idea?

Thanks

Togo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, no. A tab in Safari has no meaning or representation elsewhere in the system. It's just data inside the Safari process which is not accessible to other processes nor would they know how to interpret it if it were.

That said, the Accessibility API is probably the closest you can get to this. An accessible app should inform the system about changes to its GUI and an accessibility client can observe that.

Comment: thanks a lot. With your hint i found the UIElementInspector project released from apple. And this is exactly what i need. How can i do something for you, flattr or something like that?